# JS what is this loop: / break loop notation?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I just came accros this code:

```
    var indx, hash;
    loop:
    for (var i in config.users) {
        if (config.users[i].email === dataValues.email) {
            indx = i;
            hash = config.users[i].hash;
            break loop;
        }
    }
```

Is this valid code? what is "loop:" ? It's hard to google 'js loop:' without just seeing the regular  for .. in/ while loops

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this valid code.

`loop` here is [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

> The labeled statement can be used with break or continue statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

**NOTE:** JavaScript has **NO** goto statement, you can only use labels with `break` or `continue`.

```js
var i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         break loop1;
      }
      document.write("i = " + i + ", j = " + j + "<br />");
   }
}
```

Comment: @lonewarrior556, i provide link to mdn in answer